# BlackBerry BrowserField Issue

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, browserfield

My BlackBerry app uses `BrowserField` to display web pages. I have implemented the `eventOccurred()` method for the `RenderingApplication`. The first page loads fine. `EVENT_BROWSER_CONTENT_CHANGED` is fired after the URL is requested (`EVENT_URL_REQUESTED`) and the first page loads fine.

A button on the first page redirects to a different page. This works on a regular browser. On the simulator, the same page gets loaded again when the button is clicked. When I debug, I see that the `EVENT_URL_REQUESTED` is getting fired but the `event.getURL()` is same as the first page URL. I don't understand whats going on and if I am missing anything very obvious. Can anyone help please?